# How to expand children div height to parent's height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the page structure as:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div> 
</div>
```

I want to set the height of .child equal to .parent's height (which is known), but without positioning the child absolute. So the result would be a list of children which are themselves as high as the parent.

Comment: they are to be positioned side-by-side, right?

Comment: no sorry, one below the other

Comment: But each has the same height as the parent? Or total height?

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't have 3 children as large as the parent without making the parent larger.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev but you can set children to each have the parent's defined height.

Comment: Of course you can. The result would be a vertical list of children with each of them having the same height of the parent. And with overflow: hidden; you can just make one child visible at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the parent's height, and then just set each child's height to 100%, and it will have each child have the same height as the parent, even if that expands the parent.

```css
.parent
.child:nth-child(1) {background-color: #f00;}
.child:nth-child(2) {background-color: #0f0;}
.child:nth-child(3) {background-color: #00f;}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `table-layout` or `flex-box`, which will make all the children equally high:

```css
.parent {border: 2px solid #ccf; height: 300px;}
.child:nth-child(1) {background-color: #f99;}
.child:nth-child(2) {background-color: #9f9;}
.child:nth-child(3) {background-color: #99f;}

.parent {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.parent .child {
  width: 33.3333%;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inherit property to inherit the heigtht of the parent element. Inherit will always take on the same value as the first element where this property is set. 
For example:

```css
.parent{
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}


.child1{
  height: inherit;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.child2{
  height: inherit;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: purple;
}

.child3{
  height: inherit;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.child4{
  height: inherit;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
   </div>
   <div class="child3">
   </div> 
    <div class="child4">
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can use CSS Flexbox to give child elements height of Parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div> 
</div>

.parent{
display:flex;
}
```